# Automation UI Test tool(Like selenium webdriver) for Silverlight webapp

Tags: silverlight, testing, ui-automation

Any pointers to any open source tools for testing Silverlight webapp.

I've gone through the net and so far found Telerik which isn't an opensource and Silvernium(Selenium+Silverlight) project.

But there aren't much people using Silvernium.

Are there any other options on going around with testing the Silverlight application apart from the above two?

Comment: I think this is more appropriate place to ask such a question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=30&q=silverlight

Comment: What's the point in automated testing of the Silverlight app if Silverlight is almost dead?

Comment: @Yabko: We are testing an application which was built ages back on silverlight. Its being integrated with another application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Specflow and White.

This is an old article, but White is still around.

http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/08/using-bdd-with-specflow-wpf-and-white_14.html